# In "Baby Rudin" Theorem 1.21 I understand how he constructed h but I'm confused about k

Tags: real-analysis

This is Rudin's proof for every real $x>0$ and every integer $n>0$ there is one and only one positive real y such that $y^n = x$.

Proof That there is at most one such $y$ is clear, since $0<y_{1}<y_{2}$ implies $y_{1}^{n}<y_{2}^{n}$
Let $E$ be the set consisting of all positive real numbers $t$ such that $t^{n}<x$
If $t=x /(1+x)$ then $0 \leq t<1 .$ Hence $t^{n} \leq t<x .$ Thus $t \in E,$ and $E$ is not empty.

If $t>1+x$ then $t^{n} \geq t>x,$ so that $t \notin E .$ Thus $1+x$ is an upper bound of $E$. Hence Theorem 1.19 implies the existence of
$$
y=\sup E
$$
To prove that $y^{n}=x$ we will show that each of the inequalities $y^{n}<x$ and $y^{n}>x$ leads to a contradiction. The identity $b^{n}-a^{n}=(b-a)\left(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2} a+\cdots+a^{n-1}\right)$ yields
the inequality
$$
b^{n}-a^{n}<(b-a) n b^{n-1}
$$
when $0<a<b$. Assume $y^{n}<x .$ Choose $h$ so that $0<h<1$ and
$$
h<\frac{x-y^{n}}{n(y+1)^{n-1}}
$$
Put $a=y, b=y+h .$ Then
$$
(y+h)^{n}-y^{n}<h n(y+h)^{n-1}<h n(y+1)^{n-1}<x-y^{n}
$$
Thus $(y+h)^{n}<x,$ and $y+h \in E .$ since $y+h>y,$ this contradicts the fact that $y$ is an upper bound of $E$. Assume $y^{n}>x .$ Put
$$
k=\frac{y^{n}-x}{n y^{n-1}}
$$
Then $0<k<y .$ If $t \geq y-k,$ we conclude that
$$
y^{n}-t^{n} \leq y^{n}-(y-k)^{n}<k n y^{n-1}=y^{n}-x
$$
Thus $t^{n}>x,$ and $t \notin E .$ It follows that $y-k$ is an upper bound of $E .$

So I got $h$ by wanting
$$
(y+h)^n < x
$$
$$
(y+h)^n - y^n < x - y^n
$$
Then using
$$
b^{n}-a^{n}<(b-a) n b^{n-1}
$$
I set $b=(y+h)$ and $a=y$ to get
$$
(y+h)^{n}-y^{n}<(y+h-y)n(y+h)^{n-1} = h n(y+h)^{n-1}
$$
Since
$$
(y+h)^{n}-y^{n}<h n(y+h)^{n-1}
$$
we can have
$$
hn(y+h)^{n-1}< x-y^n
$$
$$
h<\frac{x-y^{n}}{n(y+h)^{n-1}}
$$
now if we let $0<h<1$ we finally get
$$
h<\frac{x-y^{n}}{n(y+1)^{n-1}}
$$
So I basically followed that same logic to try and come up with $k$
$$
(y-k)^n>x
$$
$$
-(y-k)^n<-x
$$
$$
y^n-(y-k)^n<y^n-x
$$
Then using
$$
b^{n}-a^{n}<(b-a) n b^{n-1}
$$
$$
y^n-(y-k)^n<(y-(y-k))ny^{n-1}
$$
$$
y^n-(y-k)^n < kny^{n-1}
$$
$$
kny^{n-1}<y^n-x
$$
$$
k<\frac{y^n-x}{ny^{n-1}}
$$
So he sets $0<k<y$ but I don't understand how he can change the $<$ to an $=$

Comment: Since you have $y^n - (y-k)^n < kny^{n-1}$ you don't need $kny^{n-1} < y^n - x$, you can have equality in the latter and still be sure that $(y-k)^n > x$ at the end.

Comment: @DanielFischer So the reason we had to leave the < for h is because h depended on h so when we switch y+h to y+1 we had to use a less than. Whereas for k we do not need this and we can use an equal sign?

Comment: By $(y+h)^n - y^n < hn(y+h)^{n-1}$ we can use any $h > 0$ with $hn(y+h)^{n-1} \leqslant x - y^n$. But while the equation $kny^{n-1} = y^n - x$ is straightforward to solve (for $k$), this is not so for $hn(y+h)^{n-1} = x - y^n$. Thus we have no simple value to use for $h$ that is guaranteed to work. Hence we use inequalities to give us an $h$ that works. But these inequalities need not be strict, we could use e.g. $$h = \min\:\biggl\{1, \frac{x-y^n}{n(y+1)^{n-1}}\biggr\}\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer Got it thanks! I was kinda over thinking it.